# Neovim runs extremly slow only on one specific file

Tags: neovim

I have a configuration file in my neovim setup that runs extremly slow. There is about a 4 second lag in every key stroke. This is a lua file. I have tried to disable LSP, disable TreeSitter, and disable my auto completion plugin. None of these make a difference. I have no trouble with any other lua file that I have found. Neovim provides no errors.

My question is what is the best way to go about trying to debug this problem?